# How to put a different picture in the same place of a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, graphics, presentations, slideshow

I want to create a beamer presentation but on each of the slides I want to add a picture in one of the corners, just that I would change it from slide to slide. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please give us some code of yours or at least a drawing of what you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need an exact placement it will be most convenient to use tikz package and `\onslide<...>` instructions:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
    
\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}{}{}

Some
\begin{itemize}
\item text
\item on the
\item slide
\end{itemize}
 
\begin{tikzpicture} [remember picture, overlay]
        \onslide<1>{
        \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east)
        {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{pic1.png}} ;}
        \onslide<2>{
        \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) 
        {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{pic2.png}} ;}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Options `remember picture, overlay` passed to the tikzpicture are there to keep any other slide content unchanged and just add a node with a picture on top.

If graphics placement is not important, then there are simpler solutions proposed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683093/beamer-how-to-show-images-as-step-by-step-images/4684091).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an abbreviation, e.g., using `\newcommand\cornerpic[1]{...}` where the parameter is the filename. Using parts of the answer from @malewick a demo code could then look like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\cornerpic}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture} [remember picture, overlay]
        \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east){%
            \includegraphics[width=5em]{#1}};%
    \end{tikzpicture}   
}


\begin{document}    
    \begin{frame}{}{}
        \cornerpic{apple.png}
        Some text 
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{}{}
        \cornerpic{banana.png}
        Some more text 
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

resulting in the following two slides:
[image]

There, the position and size are "hard coded" in the `\newcommand` and only the filename needs to be provided.